# What is the relationship between page weight (in KB) and HTTP requests in page speed?

Tags: performance, http

Setting aside the user's connection speed, I've been wondering if there is a ratio between page weight and HTTP requests in page speed.

For instance:

1. Does the page weight or HTTP requests affect page speed more
2. If I increase my page weight but decreased my HTTP requests could I maintain my average page load time

I know this is an over simplification of the topic but I was wondering if anyone has any insight into this?

Comment: There are no general answers to your questions. All that can be said is: "it depends". But there is one sure way to find out what the answers are in your particular situation: try it.

Answer (score 1):

We have been conducting extensive experiments on reducing the page weight. Here are some factors to consider:

- request count is not the only factor; blocking requests are far more costly than non-blocking ones
- certain resources by nature incurs more weight
- combination of shadows, gradients, etc., can significantly slow down render time
- try to keep your requests per page under 10. most browsers allow only 6 concurrent connections per domain. if you have more than that, shard the domains

Hope this helps.